# Error:(238, 60) error: incompatible types: Query cannot be converted to QueryParameters?

Tags: java, android

Writing in Java within Android Studio. The class appears as:

```
// Query dynamic map service layer by QueryTask
private class RunQueryDynamicLayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, FeatureSet> {
    private Envelope env;
    private SpatialReference sr;
    private int id;
    private Layer layer;
    private int subLayerId;

    public RunQueryDynamicLayerTask(Envelope env, Layer layer, int subLayerId, SpatialReference sr, int id) {
        super();
        this.env = env;
        this.sr = sr;
        this.id = id;
        this.layer = layer;
        this.subLayerId = subLayerId;
    }


    @Override
    protected FeatureSet doInBackground(String... urls) {
        for (String url : urls) {
            // Retrieve features within the envelope.
            Query query = new Query();
            query.setInSpatialReference(sr);
            query.setOutSpatialReference(sr);
            query.setGeometry(env);
            query.setMaxFeatures(10);
            query.setOutFields(new String[]{"*"});

            QueryTask queryTask = new QueryTask(url);
            try {
                FeatureSet results = queryTask.execute(query);
                return results;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final FeatureSet result) {
        count.decrementAndGet();
        if (result == null) {
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing() && count.intValue() == 0)
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            return;
        }

        Feature[] features = result.getGraphics();
        if (features == null || features.length == 0) {
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing() && count.intValue() == 0)
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            return;
        }
        // Check if the requested PopupContainer id is the same as the current PopupContainer.
        // Otherwise, abandon the obsoleted query result.
        if (id != popupContainer.hashCode()) {
            // Dismiss spinner
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing() && count.intValue() == 0)
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            return;
        }
        PopupInfo popupInfo = layer.getPopupInfo(subLayerId);
        if (popupInfo == null) {
            // Dismiss spinner
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing() && count.intValue() == 0)
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            return;
        }

        for (Feature fr : features) {
            Popup popup = layer.createPopup(map, subLayerId, fr);
            popupContainer.addPopup(popup);
        }
        createPopupViews(features, id);

    }
}
```

However, I get the error, 'Error:(238, 60) error: incompatible types: Query cannot be converted to    QueryParameters' from this line:

```
FeatureSet results = queryTask.execute(query);
```

What should I do to solve this incompatibility issue?

Comment: Either find a different `execute()` method that lets you use a `Query`, or replace `Query` with `QueryParameters`, apparently. Ideally, this would be covered in the documentation for whatever library or other code base that you are using here.

Comment: `QueryTask` doesn't take a query. Are you sure you don't mean `Query.execute()`?

Comment: I cannot cast a Query to a QueryParameters so I will try to find another method to replace execute().

Comment: Or you may want to make the variable `query` of type `QueryParameters`.

Comment: QueryTask expects `QueryParameters` so should provide it.  Your variable `query` looks like it is of type `QueryParameters`, not `Query` (based on the calls you're doing with it).

Comment: So I did that and the error resolved to the 'FeatureSet results' and is now saying that I cannot convert a 'FeatureResult' (what the 'queryTask' object is hopefully returning) to a 'FeatureSet' (what 'results' is).